# WebdriverIO Custom Reporter - TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, webstorm, webdriver-io, reporters

I am setting up a custom reporter in WebdriverIO.  This is currently my code:

```
let WDIOReporter = require ('@wdio/reporter');

module.exports = class HTMLReporter extends WDIOReporter {
    constructor (options) {
        super(options);
        console.log('initialized custom reporter with the following reporter options: ', options);
    }
}
```

When I run my program, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:...\reporting\index.js:3:45)`

This seems to be causing an error at the `module.exports = class HTMLReporter extends WDIOReporter` line.

How can I fix this issue?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Do `require ('@wdio/reporter').default` instead.

Comment: To add some further context, this is because in @wdio/reporter/build/index.js the WDIOReporter class is exported as 'exports.default = WDIOReporter;'